# Get non existing element from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two arrays

```
var a = [{'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12}, {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13}, {'Id': 4, 'name':'prasad', 'age':25}];
var b = [{'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12}, {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13}];
```

I want to compare each element of array a with array b based on ID (Ids are unique always) and want only record which present in array a but not in array b

Here expected output would be

```
{'Id': 4, 'name':'prasad', 'age':25}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
for (var elementA of a) {
    var uniqueElement = true;
    for (var elementB of b) {
         //if condition chekcs elementA.Id and elementB.Id
         //setting values
    }
}
```

I believe there will be elegant approve to solve this?

Comment: Could be done using one liner: `a.find(elA => !b.find(elB => elB.Id === elA.Id))`

Comment: Thank you all for your overwhelming response, I will try each and every suggestions. It would be great if you help me with explanation as **I am new to typescript, javascript too**

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar there's not even one answer written in TS :)

Comment: @ponury-kostek, good catch.. I updated my comment.. Solutions are working like a charm..Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following. Create a **Set** of **Ids** of `b` array and then filter array `a` based on that.

**CASE 1**: Use **Array.filter** in case of more than 1 entry

```js
var a = [{'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12}, {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13}, {'Id': 4, 'name':'prasad', 'age':25}];
var b = [{'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12}, {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13}];

var objB = b.reduce((a,c) => a.add(c.Id), new Set());

var result = a.filter(v => !objB.has(v.Id));
console.log(result);
```

**CASE 2**: Use **Array.find** in case of 1 entry

```js
var a = [{'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12}, {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13}, {'Id': 4, 'name':'prasad', 'age':25}];
var b = [{'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12}, {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13}];

var objB = b.reduce((a,c) => a.add(c.Id), new Set());

var result = a.find(v => !objB.has(v.Id));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If only single object is expected then `Array#find` could be used instead of `Array#filter`. Good use of `Set` ;)

Comment: @Rayon - Agreed. I will update the answer covering both the scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this one working as expected.. Thanks Nikhil

Answer (score 1):

With ES6:

```
const idsFromB = b.map(item => item.Id)
const c = a.filter(item => idsFromB.indexOf(item.Id) < 0)
//outputs [{'Id': 4, 'name':'prasad', 'age':25}]
```

Comment: More readable and easy to understand. I tried this as well.. working as expected. but sorry I can accept only one answer... Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [{ 'Id': 1, 'name': 'bob', 'age': 22 }, { 'Id': 2, 'name': 'alice', 'age': 12 }, { 'Id': 3, 'name': 'mike', 'age': 13 }, { 'Id': 4, 'name': 'prasad', 'age': 25 }];
var b = [{ 'Id': 1, 'name': 'bob', 'age': 22 }, { 'Id': 2, 'name': 'alice', 'age': 12 }, { 'Id': 3, 'name': 'mike', 'age': 13 }];

const na = [];

a.filter((_a) => {
    let isNotUnique = true;
    for (var elementB of b) {
        if (_a.Id === elementB.Id) {
            isNotUnique = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (isNotUnique) {
        na.push(_a);
    }
    
});

console.log(na);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) problem.

```js
var a = [
  {'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22},
  {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12},
  {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13},
  {'Id': 4, 'name':'prasad', 'age':25}
];
var b = [
  {'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22},
  {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12},
  {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13}
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(diff(a, b), null, 2));

function diff(a, b) {
  return a.filter(x => !b.some(y => deepCompare(x, y)));
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/1762224
function deepCompare(){var t,e,r,n;function o(t,e){var f;if(isNaN(t)&&isNaN(e)&&"number"==typeof t&&"number"==typeof e)return!0;if(t===e)return!0;if("function"==typeof t&&"function"==typeof e||t instanceof Date&&e instanceof Date||t instanceof RegExp&&e instanceof RegExp||t instanceof String&&e instanceof String||t instanceof Number&&e instanceof Number)return t.toString()===e.toString();if(!(t instanceof Object&&e instanceof Object))return!1;if(t.isPrototypeOf(e)||e.isPrototypeOf(t))return!1;if(t.constructor!==e.constructor)return!1;if(t.prototype!==e.prototype)return!1;if(r.indexOf(t)>-1||n.indexOf(e)>-1)return!1;for(f in e){if(e.hasOwnProperty(f)!==t.hasOwnProperty(f))return!1;if(typeof e[f]!=typeof t[f])return!1}for(f in t){if(e.hasOwnProperty(f)!==t.hasOwnProperty(f))return!1;if(typeof e[f]!=typeof t[f])return!1;switch(typeof t[f]){case"object":case"function":if(r.push(t),n.push(e),!o(t[f],e[f]))return!1;r.pop(),n.pop();break;default:if(t[f]!==e[f])return!1}}return!0}if(arguments.length<1)return!0;for(t=1,e=arguments.length;t<e;t++)if(r=[],n=[],!o(arguments[0],arguments[t]))return!1;return!0}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.filter()` to filter the first array (if the second `Array.some()` has an element with the first array `Id`).

The result of `arr2.some()` is inverted to include only the ones that are not in `arr1`.

```js
    let arr1 = [{'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12}, {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13}, {'Id': 4, 'name':'prasad', 'age':25}];
let arr2 = [{'Id': 1, 'name':'bob', 'age':22}, {'Id': 2, 'name':'alice', 'age':12}, {'Id': 3, 'name':'mike', 'age':13}];
    
let result = arr1.filter(x=>!arr2.some(y=>x.Id===y.Id));
console.log(result)    // output: [{'Id': 4, 'name':'prasad', 'age':25}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var c;

a.forEach((aobj) => {
c = 0;
b.forEach((bobj) => {
if (aobj.Id === bobj.Id) {
  c++;
 }
})
 if (c === 0) console.log(aobj);
})`
```